# `runuser` command giving permissions error

Tags: linux, permissions

I am getting following error when trying to use runuser command.

```
[pradeep.c@haproxy ~]$ echo $USER
pradeep.c
[pradeep.c@haproxy ~]$ runuser pradeep.c
runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted
```

Can someone explain me how i can prevent this. Is there any config file for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have logged in as normal user pradeep.c, but to get any user's shell you need root priviliges. In other words this command can run from root you can use screen command to open another screen of pradeep.c user and su command to login with any other user.